# "Register New Service Endpoint" is missing in PlugIn Registration inside the XRM Toolbox

Tags: azure, plugins, dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

I have downloaded the latest XRM Toolbox and is using the PlugIn Registration in the XRM Toolbox.

I have created a Azure Service Bus and wanted to connect it to a particular entity on an environment I have connected on PlugIn Registration tool.

However, under "Register", I only have the choices of "Register New Assembly", "Register New Step", "Register New Image" and "Register New Webhook".

I do not have a choice of "Register New Service Endpoint". Could someone please help to answer why this is the case and how I can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin Registration Tool inside XrmToolBox is a community tool based on the source code of the PRT for CRM 2011 released by Microsoft.

The recent versions of PRT do not include the source code, so the community version is missing some functionalities.

You will need to use the PRT from Microsoft, you can find it on NuGet

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PluginRegistrationTool/

or you can use PAC CLI (instruction here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/download-tools-nuget#download-and-launch-tools-using-power-platform-cli)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I couldn't use the latest PlugIn tool from NuGet to connect to the dataverse in the organization due to the network set up from the organization given laptop. That's why I have been using the XRM Tool box instead and was suspecting that "Register New Service Endpoint" needs to be on the PlugIn through NuGet as well... That clarify it. Thank you for your help.